# Iteration to place widgets in Tkinter and Pmw

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, refactoring, pmw

I have massively reduced the amount of repetitive code by using a loop in Python to create, format and store Pmw EntryFields in my project rather than build individual widgets. I even managed to place them in  a linear fashion on the root window -- one under the other in column 0.

However, when I want to place them in two columns I cannot find a way to generate the following widget row and column coordinates

**(0,0)(0 1),(1,0)(1,1)(2,0)(2,1)** from the for  loop. I used a workaround which was to type the above coordinates into a Python list and refer to the list.

```
import tkinter
import Pmw
import time



root=tkinter.Tk()                                         #Create a main GUI window

root.option_readfile('optionDB')                          #Override Windows default fonts
##root.resizable(width=False, height=False)                #Fix the window size in stone
root.iconbitmap('logo.ico')                               #add logo
titles=['a', 'b','c', 'd','e','f']                        #List ttitles of entry fields
**locations=[(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(2,1)]**           #Entry locations
entry ={}                                                 #Container for referencing entry fieleds



for nextWidget in range(len(titles)):                    #Buils widgets on the page                        

    dummy_x= Pmw.EntryField(root,                                           #widget properties
                               labelpos = 'w',
                               label_text = titles[nextWidget],
                               label_fg="white",
                               entry_width=10
                           )
    Pmw.Color.changecolor(dummy_x.component("hull"),
                                 background="blue")

    **dummy_x.grid(row= locations[nextWidget][0],**
                      column=locations[nextWidget][1],
                      padx=10,pady=10
                )

    entry.update({titles[nextWidget]: dummy_x})                             #add to container


root.mainloop()        #run the venet loop
```

You can see in the main for loop I iterate over the **list called locations** and placing the values in the row, column attributes of the grid() option to place the widgets.

**Question:**
To **eliminate the locations list** altogether is there a way to generate the sequence (0,0)(0 1),(1,0)(1,1)(2,0)(2,1) from the for loop iteself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer for all cases is you can use a for()

```
for this_row in range(3):
    for this_column in range(2):
         print this_row, this_column
```

or increment counters

```
this_row=0
this_column=0
for nextWidget in range(len(titles)): 
    ...
    this_column += 1
    if this_column > 1:
        this_row += 1
        this_column = 0
```

or test for nextWidget%2 = similar to above but divmod works better than modulus for this

```
for ctr in range(6):
    print divmod(ctr, 2)
```

Comment: Did you figure this out from scratch or have you come across it before? If you figured it out can you let me know how you solved it as I am embarrassed to say I gave up! I had come to the mod idea but never thought to pair it with div! Thanks

Comment: Having refactored the code using the divmod methos am beginning to think my original is less cryptic for someone to maintain - any opinions?

Comment: "lesscryptic" depends on who is maintaining it is a value judgement.  It is straight forward and obvious IMHO, and the result can be printed if someone is not familiar with divmod.

Comment: Note also that your solution is not general, i.e. it only works for one specific group.

Comment: Yes but i often find when making ďatabase solutions I mostly use only two patterns which is one or two column guis.Thanks for opinion it will help stimulate dicussion in my classroom.

Answer (score 1):

`(i/2, i%2)` (python2), or `(i//2, i%2)` (python3) will will give you the numbers you want, if you only need two columns

```
$ python3 -i
Python 3.4.0 (default, Jun 19 2015, 14:20:21) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print((i//2, i%2))
... 
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 0)
(2, 1)
(3, 0)
(3, 1)
(4, 0)
(4, 1)
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, I ticked Curly Jo as he was the oldest post but I like all answers equally, it doesn't let me tick two answers.

Comment: @TimothyLawman: I honestly don't care. Pick the one that helped.

Comment: I have a question posted no one has answered yet going back over a year - how to send contents of a Tkinter text widget to the local printer from a button? Have you ever done this in you day to day work?

Comment: @TimothyLawman: nope, I haven't use a printer at work in a decade. I assume there are python libraries for dealing with printers, but I've never used them.

Comment: good idea I will see if there is a library, I never thought to do this

Comment: In Linux you copy the text to a file and call lpr on the file.  You should use the OS's built in print spooler to do it as it already exists and is know to work without problems.